# Drag & Drop in Ioinic with react to app Android

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop

I have created an app with ionic and react that has three columns in which I move Cards. As if it were a canvas of tasks to be carried out, working and finished.

I have used in the columns onDragOver and onDrop, and then in the Cards: draggable and onDragStart.

```
<IonCol 
  onDragOver={ draggingOver } 
  onDrop={ onDroppedToUnblocked }
  >
 
  <CardOrder
     draggable 
     onDragStart={ dragStarted }>
  />

</IonCol>
```

In my browser it works, but when creating the app with android, on android tablet or mobile devices, this functionality does not work.

I haven't found anything like it yet, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this doesn't work on Android, so I've used Ionic's Gesture event.
The way to use it is totally different from drag and drop in JS, because with Gesture you need to manage where to drop the element using its x-axis and y-axis.